# Sizes of rectangles in hierarchiecal tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-trees, size

I am trying to create a hierarchical diagram with multiple levels using Tikz' child function. However, it looks bad as the sizes of boxes differ (even after adjusting number of lines artificially). Anybody knows how to fix the size of the rectangles?

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{MWE}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=6em,level distance=5em,every node/.style={shape=rectangle,draw,align=center}]
        %\begin{tikzpicture}[
        %every node/.style={shape=rectangle,draw,align=center}]
        \node{\footnotesize Some title at the top \\ \footnotesize (ALMP)}
            child{node{\footnotesize ahsfafasd \\ \footnotesize aasfasf}}
            child{node{\footnotesize Trasfas \\ \footnotesize asfasms}}
            child{node{\footnotesize afst \\ \footnotesize incasfasves}
                child{node{\footnotesize asfasf \\ \footnotesize supplements}}
                child{node{\footnotesize Hfass \\ \footnotesize fasfas}}
                child{node{\footnotesize sfasdf \\ \footnotesize fasfas}}}
            child{node{\footnotesize efaecfasd \\ \footnotesize joasfas}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: You have to fix a `minimum height` and `minimum width` large enough to contain the largest text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{MWE}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    sibling distance=6em,
    level distance=5em,
    every node/.style={draw, 
                       text width=5em, align=center,
                       minimum height=6ex, 
                       execute at end node=\vphantom{p},
                       font=\footnotesize}
                    ]
\node{Some title at the top (ALMP)}
    child{node{ahsfafasd  aasfasf}}
    child{node{Trasfas  asfasms}}
    child{node{afst incasfasves}
                child{node{asfasf supplements}}
                child{node{Hfass fasfas}}
                child{node{sfasdf fasfas}}
        }
    child{node{efaecfasd joasfas}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In the case, if you like to have wider root node, than for it write:

```
\node[text width=8em] {Some title at the top\\ (ALMP)}
```

and the compilation result will be:

[image]

**Addendum:**
With use of the `forest` package the code for your tree is simpler and shorter:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{MWE}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    draw, 
where level=0{text width=8em}{text width=5em}, 
    text centered,
    minimum height=6ex, 
    execute at end node=\vphantom{p},
    font=\footnotesize,
% tree
    anchor=north,
    l sep=12mm,
    s sep=2mm,
            }
[Some title at the top\\ (ALMP) 
    [ahsfafasd  aasfasf]
    [Trasfas  asfasms]
    [afst incasfasves 
        [asfasf supplements]
        [Hfass fasfas]
        [sfasdf fasfas]
    ]
    [efaecfasd joasfas]
]
\end{forest}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! There is still differences in the lowest level, but I guess that's because it has two lines.

Comment: @Papayapap, not anymore. See edited answer and also addendum.